# Sum of similar elements in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I get input xml as :

```
 <root>
<SalesOrderLine>
<Item><ID>1056365</ID></Item>
<Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
<UnitPrice><UnitAmount>4.4</UnitAmount></UnitPrice>
</SalesOrderLine>
<SalesOrderLine>
<Item><ID>1056365</ID></Item>
<Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
<UnitPrice><UnitAmount>8.4</UnitAmount></UnitPrice>
</SalesOrderLine>
<SalesOrderLine>
<Item><ID>1056366</ID></Item>
<Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
<UnitPrice><UnitAmount>0.00</UnitAmount></UnitPrice>
</SalesOrderLine>
</root>
```

The expected output xml is :

```
<root1>
<SL>
<Item><ID>1056365</ID></Item>
<Quantity>2.00</Quantity>
<UnitPrice><UnitAmount>6.4</UnitAmount></UnitPrice>
</SL>
<SL>
<Item><ID>1056366</ID></Item>
<Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
<UnitPrice><UnitAmount>0.00</UnitAmount></UnitPrice>
</SL>
</root>
```

line quantity = sum (line quantity with same item id)
line amount = sum (line quantity * line price) / sum (line quantity with same item id)

Can anybody please suggest how to achieve using XSLT ?

Comment: See the grouping examples in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples to have a starting point, you can then nearly express stuff like `sum (line quantity with same item id)` as `sum(current-group()/Quantity)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the XSL you're looking for. It uses a variable inside the for-each-group to calculate each Sales Order Line's actual total (i.e. its quantity times its unit price). That variable is then summed and divided by the quantity sum to properly calculate the overall unit price.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="root">
    <root1>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="SalesOrderLine" group-by="Item/ID">
            <xsl:variable name="QuantitySum" select="sum(current-group()/Quantity)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="SLTotals">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <SLTotal><xsl:value-of select="Quantity * UnitPrice/UnitAmount"/></SLTotal>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <SL>
                <Item>
                    <ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </ID>
                </Item>
                <Quantity>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$QuantitySum"/>
                </Quantity>
                <UnitPrice>
                    <UnitAmount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum($SLTotals/SLTotal) div $QuantitySum"/>
                    </UnitAmount>
                </UnitPrice>
            </SL>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root1>
</xsl:template>
```