# XSLT grouping and summing

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I am new to XSLT and need to sum the total price (Quantity * UnitPrice) of items based on ID from each orders, and print it at the end of each Item's group using XSLT 1.0.
Here is my example XML

```
<Orders>
<Order>
    <Reference>234</Reference>
    <Item>
        <ID>10</ID>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>2</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>10</ID>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>3</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>10</ID>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>2</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>20</ID>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>4</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
</Order>
<Order>
    <Reference>456</Reference>
    <Item>
        <ID>10</ID>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>2</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>20</ID>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>2</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

The desired output XML is below

```
<SAPOrders>
<Order>
    <Reference>234</Reference>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>2</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>3</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>2</UnitPrice>
        <Total>12</Notes>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>4</UnitPrice>
        <Total>8</Notes>
    </Item>
</Order>
<Order>
    <Reference>456</Reference>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>2</UnitPrice>
        <Total>4</Notes>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>2</UnitPrice>
        <Total>4</Total>
    </Item>
</Order>
</SAPOrders>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205574/sum-of-similar-elements-in-xslt which is a near duplicate

Comment: @MichaelKay You're pointing to an XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: @tojira Why are there no item IDs in the output?

Comment: @michael.hor257k there are logic for the output xml and won't just be copying.

Comment: I can't say I understand your reply, but if that's how you want it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here: (1) group the items by order **and** by item ID, and (2) calculate the subtotal for each such group.

The first problem is relatively easy and can be solved using the [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) method. The second problem is more difficult, since XSLT 1.0 does not allow summing the result of a calculation.

The following stylesheet starts by pre-calculating the extended price of each item and storing the results in a variable. Then it operates on the variable, grouping the items and subtotaling each group.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="Item" use="@key" />

<xsl:template match="/Orders">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
        <xsl:for-each select="Order">
            <Order>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Reference"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="Item">
                    <Item key="{concat(../Reference, '|', ID)}" extPrice="{Quantity * UnitPrice}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                    </Item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Order>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <SAPOrders>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($first-pass)/Order">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Reference"/>
                <!-- for each unique item in this order -->
                <xsl:for-each select="Item[count(. | key('item', @key)[1]) = 1]">
                    <!-- list the items in this group -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('item', @key)">
                        <Item>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="Quantity | UnitPrice"/>
                            <!-- add the subtotal of this group -->
                            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                                <Total>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('item', @key)/@extPrice)" />
                                </Total>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </Item>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </SAPOrders>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuPz