# Merge similar nodes into one node and do mathematical operation with the element value in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have one input xml and want to merge matching nodes into one node based on some condition of element value and also add the numeric value of element into the same one node.

```
<OrderDetails>
   <Details>
     <OrderId>1</OrderId>
     <NameOfItem>item1</NameOfItem>
     <quantity>5</quantity>
     <price>50</price>
   </Details>
   <Details>
     <OrderId>2</OrderId>
     <NameOfItem>item2</NameOfItem>
     <quantity>8</quantity>
     <price>64</price>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <OrderId>1</OrderId>
    <NameOfItem>item1</NameOfItem>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <price>20</price>
  </Details>
</OrderDetails>
```

Expect the output as

```
<OrderDetails>
  <Details>
   <OrderId>1</OrderId>
   <NameOfItem>item1</NameOfItem>
   <quantity>7</quantity>
   <price>70</price>
 </Details>
 <Details>
  <OrderId>2</OrderId>
  <NameOfItem>item2</NameOfItem>
  <quantity>8</quantity>
  <price>64</price>
 </Details>
</OrderDetails>
```

I was trying to apply muenchian method for grouping like below in my XSLT. Writing only template part.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <OrderDetails>
     <xsl:for-each select="/OrderDetails/Details">
        <Details>
          <xsl:for-each select="/OrderDetails/Details/OrderId[not(. = preceding::Details/OrderId)]">
        <OrderId>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </OrderId>
                    </xsl:for-each>
           <NameOfItem>
              <xsl:value-of select="NameOfItem"/>
           </NameOfItem>
           <quantity>
              <!--addition function required-->
             <xsl:value-of select="quantity"/>
           </quantity>
           <price>
              <!--addition function required-->
              <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
           </price>
        </Details>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </OrderDetails>
</xsl:template>
```

But unable to get my desired output and want to sum the **quantity** and **price** value. Finding solution for this. Getting output as

```
<OrderDetails>
  <Details>
    <OrderId>1</OrderId>
    <OrderId>2</OrderId>
    <NameOfItem>item1</NameOfItem>
    <quantity>5</quantity>
    <price>50</price>
 </Details>
 <Details>
   <OrderId>1</OrderId>
   <OrderId>2</OrderId>
   <NameOfItem>item2</NameOfItem>
   <quantity>8</quantity>
   <price>64</price>
</Details>
<Details>
  <OrderId>1</OrderId>
  <OrderId>2</OrderId>
  <NameOfItem>item1</NameOfItem>
  <quantity>2</quantity>
  <price>20</price>
</Details>
</OrderDetails>
```

Please help with XSLT 1.0.XSLT 2.0 is also much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please choose either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, as the methods are very different. If you can use XSLT 2.0, why would you ask about XSLT 1.0? -- BTW, what you started to apply is **not** the Muenchian method.  You can see how to handle this in XSLT 1.0, using the Muenchian method., here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549625/xslt-grouping-and-summing/41564043#41564043

Comment: michael, currently i am working with XSLT 1.0. so it would be great if i get answer in XSLT 1.0. Thanks

Comment: Well, then you already have an answer.

Comment: I went through your previous solution but this is a little bit different as because there recursive node is still present in output xml but here i want total in one node and not adding any extra element to parent node like <total>. Hope you understand.